# Switch to popup in python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I switch to a popup window in the below selenium program. I've looked up for all possible solutions but haven't been able to get my head around them. Please help!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from splinter import Browser
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
handle = []
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://example.com/test.aspx")

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Site Actions").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Edit Page').click()
select = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl35_ctl00_SelectResult')
for option in select.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl35_ctl00_SelectResult"]/option'):
            if option.text != 'Channel':
                option.select() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver

driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl35_ctl00_RemoveButton').click()

parent_h = driver.current_window_handle

#click that activates the popup.
checkIn = driver.find_element_by_id('qaCheckin_anchor').click()

# click on the link that opens a new window
handles = driver.window_handles # before the pop-up window closes
driver.remove(parent_h)
driver.switch_to_window(handles.pop())
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('btnClose2').click()
driver.close();
# do stuff in the popup
# popup window closes
driver.switch_to_window(parent_h)
# and you're back

driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch to web dialog box in selenium webdriver: Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290077/switch-to-web-dialog-box-in-selenium-webdriver-python)

Comment: @vks Thanks. I've tried implementing the solutions form the above link. However, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: still not working. I am working on a sharepoint page if that helps.

Comment: it's a web pop up.. with check boxes

Comment: which operation are you going to do with pop up? just click Yes/No?

Comment: Its a SharePoint webpart pop-up I can OK it or cancel.

Answer (score 4):

in terms of browser, pop up is not a window, it is an alert. so, you should use following:

```
driver.switch_to_alert()
```

Comment: No, it actually is a window.

Comment: I am having the same issue.