# the OK button can't be click - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The below is the id of the "Ok" button inside the popup window , just wanted to say that i was able to sendkeys and ENTER for another field inside the same popup window :
[OK button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFJvw.png)

The exception i'm getting is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Cannot click on element
```

Also adding the actual GUI :
[actual window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIfgU.png)

The code is below:

```
def create_new_customer_iden():
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#customer_care_app_tab > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)").click()
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#add_customer > td:nth-child(2)").click()
    browser.find_element_by_id("go_srch_button").click()
    random_number=random.randrange (10000, 99999)
    statement ='INSERT INTO sa_customer(CUSTOMER_NO, CUSTOMER_NAME) VALUES(:1, :2)'
    cursor.execute(statement,(random_number,random_number))
    connection.commit()
    browser.find_element_by_name("popup_search_init_customer_id").send_keys(random_number)
    browser.find_element_by_name("popup_search_init_customer_id").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    # works great until here
    browser.find_element_by_id("ok_button").click()
```

i found another issue :
if i'm adding the below lines of code :

```
button=browser.find_element_by_id ("ok_button")
print(button)
button.click()
```

The print gives me this element:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="75fba3d3-bef4-4800-a03d-bfbfcf831209", element="4d27c723-ed64-40a5-9da0-102a52f4d910")
```

BUT the last line of code throws me the below exception :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Cannot click on element
```

WHICH means that i need to find a subtitute to the click() operation.
Any suggestions ???

Comment: You're gonna have to show us the code you already have, and perhaps a link to the page if possible.

Comment: I edited my question with the added code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve ElementNotInteractableException in Selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following once the popup loads - `driver.switch_to_frame(webelement)` / `driver.switch_to_window(window_name)`

Once you've finished interacting with the popup, e.g. you've closed it use `driver.switch_to_default_content()` to return to the main page

window_name can be defined by

`var window_name` = `driver.find_element_by_class_name("popup_table")`

If none of the above works, the last thing I can suggest to try is: `driver.switch_to_alert()`

For more information please see: [Python webdriver to handle pop up browser windows which is not an alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676036/python-webdriver-to-handle-pop-up-browser-windows-which-is-not-an-alert)

[Switch to popup in python using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858434/switch-to-popup-in-python-using-selenium)

I'd also suggest reading through the Python documentation: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html - you'll probably find the answer here if the above doesn't help. I'm not really familiar with Python

Comment: it's not defined as iframe but as div id

Comment: What is the window name according to the DOM I've attached ?- i tried any name there and it didn't work

Comment: no still : selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Cannot click on element

Comment: try read this https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/switching-between-windows-and-alerts/ and http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this and then see what exception is thrown?

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ok_button")))
```

Comment: the exception : raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

How about using `XPath` or `selector`? Chrome DevTools provide them.

Here's the sample code

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("insert ok_button xpath").click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("insert ok_button selector").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

"The print gives me this element: selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="75fba3d3-bef4-4800-a03d-bfbfcf831209", element="4d27c723-ed64-40a5-9da0-102a52f4d910") BUT the last line of code throws me the below exception : selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Cannot click on element WHICH means that i need to find a subtitute to the click() operation. Any suggestions ???"

Yes, try the below:

```
def create_new_customer_iden():
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#customer_care_app_tab > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)").click()
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#add_customer > td:nth-child(2)").click()
    browser.find_element_by_id("go_srch_button").click()
    random_number=random.randrange (10000, 99999)
    statement ='INSERT INTO sa_customer(CUSTOMER_NO, CUSTOMER_NAME) VALUES(:1, :2)'
    cursor.execute(statement,(random_number,random_number))
    connection.commit()
    browser.find_element_by_name("popup_search_init_customer_id").send_keys(random_number)
    browser.find_element_by_name("popup_search_init_customer_id").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("popup_table")
browser.switch_to_window(window_name)

okButton = browser.find_element_by_id("ok_button")
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(okButton).perform()
actions.click(okButton)
//some action to close the popup
browser.switch_to_default_content()
```

if not, try this...

```
def create_new_customer_iden():
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#customer_care_app_tab > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)").click()
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#add_customer > td:nth-child(2)").click()
    browser.find_element_by_id("go_srch_button").click()
    random_number=random.randrange (10000, 99999)
    statement ='INSERT INTO sa_customer(CUSTOMER_NO, CUSTOMER_NAME) VALUES(:1, :2)'
    cursor.execute(statement,(random_number,random_number))
    connection.commit()
    browser.find_element_by_name("popup_search_init_customer_id").send_keys(random_number)
    browser.find_element_by_name("popup_search_init_customer_id").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.switch_to_alert()

okButton = browser.find_element_by_id("ok_button")
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(okButton).perform()
actions.click(okButton)
//some action to close the popup
browser.switch_to_default_content()
```

Obviously you may need to change this slightly to fit in with your code, e.g. browser instead of driver.

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

Comment: Nothing happens - it is just stuck on the last line of code- the OK button is not clicked and the screen with the popup remains open forever

Comment: still nothing happens - just stuck on the popup window and not clickingg

Comment: try this first driver.switch_to_alert()

Comment: Nope, added also that and still freezing

Comment: Hmm I'm not too sure then, if you provide the web link for the page then I could possibly have a look

Comment: Its intranet - can't be entered outside the organization 

Comment: Okay, well I've updated my answer one last time, if this doesn't work, I'm completely out of ideas...

Comment: The first solution exception is : urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>

The second solution just made it freeze again.

Comment: This is just an Enigma - i will find it out tomorrow with our developers because i really tried any possible solution. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue was solved eventually by me :
it appears that there are 2 buttons with the same ID - so i added index as below :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[@id="ok_button"])[2]').click()
```

IT WORKED !!!!