# Cannot switch to the facebook login alert as the window name changes everytime

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I have been using the code below to log into Spotify using facebook credentials.

This is the code I am using:

```
__author__ = 'hoaxcracker'
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Time_list=[]
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://play.spotify.com")
driver.find_element_by_id('fb-login-btn').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys("email@domain.com")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys("passwrd")
time.sleep(1)
```

I also tried using the code below from [Switch to web dialog box in selenium webdriver: Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290077/switch-to-web-dialog-box-in-selenium-webdriver-python) but no help. I found out that fb login works a little different as it generates new tokens every time.

So after that the new code is

```
__author__ = 'hoaxcracker'
from splinter import browser


import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Time_list=[]
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://play.spotify.com")
parent_h = browser.current_window_handle
driver.find_element_by_id('fb-login-btn').send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # click on the link that opens a new window
handles = browser.window_handles # before the pop-up window closes
handles.remove(parent_h)
browser.switch_to_window(handles.pop())
driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys("email@domain.com")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys("passwrd")
time.sleep(1)
# do stuff in the popup
# popup window closes
browser.switch_to_window(parent_h)
```

Then I get this error!

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/veer/PycharmProjects/DryRun/login.py", line 12, in 
>       parent_h = browser.current_window_handle AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'current_window_handle'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: What is `browser`? Instance of `webdriver.Firefox()` is called `driver`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code line to correctly switch to `Facebook` authorization window:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Complete code might looks like:

```
Time_list=[]
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://play.spotify.com")
driver.find_element_by_id('fb-login-btn').send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # click on the link that opens a new window
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys("email@domain.com")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys("passwrd")
time.sleep(1)
# do stuff in the popup
driver.find_element_by_name('login').click()
time.sleep(1)
# No need to switch to main window (if authorization successful)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Will need to read more on it! Big smile on my face. :)